# Calculate Pearson's Correlation using Geometry with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, correlation

In order to calculate Pearson's correlation in Excel i am focused in calculating Cos(θ) = x'y/||x||*||y||   where x' is the transpose of the vector x and ||.|| is te norm of the vector, if i define Y' = y- µ_y and X'=x- µ,_x then Cos(θ)=ρ , where ρ is the Pearson's correlation .   Now i am triying to do so in VBA code:
    [Code in VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSPFY.jpg)

but i got an error

Could you give a little help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please copy and paste your code.  Screenshots are incredibly difficult to work with here.

Comment: Your `matrix` variables are 2D 1-based arrays (numRows x numCols), not 1D arrays which is how you seem to be treating them.

Comment: @TimWilliams You were completely right i have achievied it! Thanks!